# (Intermediate Analysis) Q: If $f :D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, show that that $|f(x)|\geq M$ for all $x\in D$ and $1/f(x)$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

### Full question:

Prove that if $f :D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, where $D$ is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$, and
if $f$ is never zero on $D$ (so $f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in D$), then

(1) there is a constant $M > 0$ such that $|f(x)|\geq M$ for all $x\in D$, and

(2) $1/f(x)$ is continuous on $D$.

### My attempt:

I am struggling really hard on how to start the problem. The logic makes sense: if $|f(x)|$ and $M$ are both greater than zero, then we can choose M to be incredibly small such that it is less than or equal to $|f(x)|$. However, I cannot think of how to approach the formal proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof of 1:

Since $f$ is continuous, then $\vert f\vert$ is continuous as well. Using $\vert f\vert$ continuous and $D$ is compact, we know $\vert f\vert$ reaches its maximum and its minimum in $D$. In particular, there is $x_m\in D$ such that for all $x\in D$, $\vert f(x_m)\vert \leq \vert f(x)\vert$.

Let $M:=\vert f(x_m)\vert$. Since $f$ is never zero in $D$, this implies $0<\vert f(x_m)\vert=M \leq\vert f(x)\vert$ for all $x\in D$

Proof of 2:

Let $y_n$ be a sequence in $D$, such that it converges to some $y\in D$. By continuity of $f$ we know the sequence $f(y_n)$ converges to $f(y)$. Then, since $f$ is not zero in $D$, $f(y_n)\neq 0$ for all $n$ and $f(y)\neq 0$. This implies the sequence $\frac{1}{f(y_n)}$ converges to $\frac{1}{f(y)}$. Since this is valid for any $y_n\rightarrow y$ we conclude $\frac{1}{f}$ is continuous.

Comment: Basically, I needed to understand the importance of D being compact. In particular, the fact that D being compact suggests there is a minimum, and I can choose M to be that minimum. Or am I misinterpreting your proof?

Comment: Yes, compact sets are very important. But you are missing the importance of $f$ being continuous as well. It is this combination ($f$ continuous and $D$ compact) which does the trick of securing that there is a minimum. And yes, you can choose $M$ to be that minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Proof by sequential compactness: Suppose that there is no such constant $M$.  Then there is a sequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ such that $f(x_i)\to 0$.  Since $D$ is compact, there is a convergent subsequence $x_{i_1}, x_{i_2}, \ldots\to y$.  But then $f(y)=0$ by continuity, contradiction.

Proof by formal nonsense: The continuous image of a compact set is compact, so $f(D)$ is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$.  Since compact sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are closed, and by assumption $0\notin f(D)$, there is an open interval around $0$ that is disjoint from $f(D)$.

Answer (score 0):

1) A continuous real map defined on a compact set attains its least and upper bounds.

The map $x \mapsto \vert f(x) \vert$ is continuous because $f$ is supposed to be continuous. Hence, there exists $x_0 \in D$ such that $\vert f(x_0) \vert$ is minimum. As $f$ is supposed to never vanish, we have $ M =\vert f(x_0) \vert >0$ and for all $x \in D$: $\vert f(x) \vert \ge M$.

2) If a real funtion $f$ is continuous and never vanishing, $\frac{1}{f}$ is defined on the domain of definition of $f$ and is continuous. Allowing us to conclude considering point 1).